# Freemarker Templates

Tags: java, freemarker, struts-1

I'm working on updating an existing application which makes use of struts 1.2.7 and tiles for the UI layer.  I'm currently replacing this with freemarker and spring webmvc.  I have some simple examples working, and am ready to start migrating the application.

How should I go about converting the tile layouts to reusable freemarker components?  I like the ease with which you can template in JSF, but am unfamiliar with how to do so in freemarker (JSF 2 also seems troublesome to get working in Tomcat 6 and offers us little, as we can not easily utilize AJAX due to 508 compliance).

My plan is to get the templates setup, and then posting the results to the struts actions.  As the templates come into place I'll then start modifying the Action code to allow us to remove Struts.  Is this a smart approach?

Comment: Found the following link which was helpful: <a href="http://richardbarabe.wordpress.com/2009/03/19/freemarker-a-brief-example/">Freemarker Template example</a>